# Can sigmoid function applied on distance calculation of Self Organizing Map improve the accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, clustering, unsupervised-learning

I just thought how sigmoid function helps logistic regression making more accurate classification and wonder if it can be applied on distance calculation of Self Organizing Map and making more better/accurate  clustering and classification? Does anybody have any suggestion is it a good idea to do it??